# Adding node value to xhtml using DOM with java

Tags: java, parsing, xhtml

I have a requirement, that i want to add body content inside the xhtml file. I have a xhtml file with empty body tag. So, i want to add the body content through java using parsers, So I am doing some thing like below , but its not working..

Can anyone tell the cause

```
org.w3c.dom.Document document=null;
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(newFile);
NodeList list =document.getElementsByTagName("body");               
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {                    
Node addBody = list.item(i);

addBody.setTextContent(bodyContent.toString());
System.out.println("text content"+addBody.getTextContent());
}
```

in the bodyContent i have some info which i want to append inside body of newFile. Even i  used the method setNodeValue(), it's also not working for me. Any thing is wrong?

I'm getting the addBody value as '[body: null]'; how to point to that body node?

Please give me any pointers..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Exception? If so, what's the stack trace? If not, what do you expect and what do you observe?

Comment: I am not getting any exception, but its not able to add the content  into the body, but  i am expecting to add the content inside the body tag

Comment: Your code works fine: if I use it on an HTML file with an empty body tag, I see the new text content displayed by the System.out.println line. What's the value of bodyContent.toString(), and what is printed on the screen by the System.out.println line?

Comment: I'm able to see the output one the System.out.println(), but addBody.setTextContent(bodyContent.toString()); is not appending into the newFile.

Comment: I'm able to see the output one the System.out.println(), but addBody.setTextContent(bodyContent.toString()); is not appending into the newFile. body.GetContent.toString() contains "helloworld" and its printing on the console as same, but not writing to the file when i open the html using browser

Answer (score 1):

When you modify the dom tree, you modify it in memory, but the original file where this dom tree comes from is not affected. You need to write the modified dom tree to the file in order to persist the changes you have made in memory.

It's exactly the same as if you read a whole file in a StringBuilder. Modifying the StringBuilder won't magically write the new content to the file.

See http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT4.html for example code to write a DOM tree to a file.

Comment: Thanks Nizet, this was useful and i am able to do append into the body.

Answer (score 0):

Node value? did you mean Text Node?
If that, you shoud create a new text node and append it to addBody. You can just call setNodeValue in a TextNode object to set the text content.
Please check http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createTextNode%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: in TestNode object there is no method like setNodeValue, i did like this TextNode t= new TextNode("<body>","</body");
addBody.setNodeValue(bodyContent.toString());
addBody.appendChild(addBody);  I'm completely new to this, thanks for your time

Comment: I dont want to create new Textnode, i want to append the data to the existing node in the file. is there any solution please tell me?